# Reactjs - want to print dynamic element

Tags: reactjs

**I am trying to create a dynamic element. whatever user input in an input box, the same number of LI element will create.**
**I get this output when I  enter 2 in input box.**

```
<li key=0>input 0</li><li key=1>input 1</li>
```

**where I want two li elements.**

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      times: 0
    };
  }
  createList = event => {
    let times = event.target.value;
    this.setState({
      times
    });
  };

  getData = times => {
    let str = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < times; i++) {
      str += "<li key=" + i + ">input " + i + "</li>";
    }
    return <ul>{str}</ul>;
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <p className="App-intro">
          <input type="number" onChange={this.createList} />
          {this.getData(this.state.times)}
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are treating them as string instead of DOM node elements. Use an array and push all the elements inside that and return the final result.

---

Don't forgot you are writing [**JSX**](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html), and `<li> input: {i+1} </li>` will get converted into:

```
React.createElement(
  "li",
  null,
  "input: ",
  i+1
);
```

But if you write: `"<li>input: {i+1}</li>"`, it will be treated as a string.

Check the complied code result of these two cases by [**Babel REPL**](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=DwGwlgfGB2AOCuAXAXAAgN5gNQEYC-wA9OBAFCkBEokMCKG2-RJFpQA&debug=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Ces2016%2Ces2017%2Creact%2Cstage-0%2Cstage-1%2Cstage-2%2Cstage-3&targets=&version=6.26.0).

**Solution:**

Write it like this:

```
getData = times => {
    let str = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < times; i++) {
      str.push(<li key={i}> input: {i+1} </li>);
    }
    return <ul>{str}</ul>;
};
```

Comment: facing any issue?